# Do I need to call SDL_GL_DeleteContext before SDL_DestroyWindow?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

In SDL if I destroy a window anyway, do I need to delete the OpenGL context beforehand or does it delete it automatically? I don't want a memory leak.

Also when do I need to call `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent`? Is this only required if I have multiple windows with a `GLcontext` each?

Couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: What do you lose by calling it? Better coherent and safe than sorry...

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, I think you're right. At first I thought it would add some code bloat, because otherwise I wouldn't need keep track of the pointer to the context, but it is honestly not that bad.

Comment: For a single window you don't have to use `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent` because `SDL_GL_CreateContext` promises to make newly created context current. Not a big deal though. If you have multiple windows or threads - that's a different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I call

```
SDL_GL_DeleteContext
SDL_DestroyWindow
SDL_QuitSubSystem
```

in that order. I once read the documentation very carefully and I remember vaguely that somewhere in the documentation this was mentioned. Although I have to warn that I read the one for SDL2. However this should be the same in SDL1.

Because all that SDL internals are easy to forget, I wrote a nice C++ wrapper:

https://github.com/Superlokkus/CG1/blob/master/src/sdl2_opengl_helper.cpp#L68

Comment: I'm also using SDL2, but couldn't find it. I've read those two sites: http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_CreateContext and http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_DeleteContext . But since it doesn't say that it will be automatically deleted either, I guess I better do it explicitlly.

Comment: I used them too, and indeed since CreateContext is even mentioning DestroyContext as a "Related Function", and in contrast to SDL_QUIT which explicity mentions what clean up calls it saves you, I am almost certain you have to destroy it, in order to avoid resource leaks.

Answer (score 2):

SDL doesn't delete the contexts automatically, you should do it manually.

Usually, my call stack goes like:

```
SDL_GL_DeleteContext(m_context);
SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
SDL_Quit();
```

Keeping track of the pointer shouldn't be that much of an issue either, since you could wrap the window system in a simple class/struct and just pass that around, like so:

```
class Window
{
public:
     SDL_Window* window;
     SDL_GLContext context;
};
```

As for your second question, each context you make is tied to the corresponding SDL window you specify when making the context current. Selecting/Making another context current and rendering on that context will draw on the window and context you make current.

You need to call `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent` once you make the window to be able to use it. When making multiple windows, make the context you want current and that will be rendered to. You should also use MakeCurrent if you're wanting to access OpenGL resources in another thread - but keep in mind that a context can only be active in ONE thread at a time, and you will have to recall the function in your main thread upon next use.

Comment: Have packed the pointers in two std::unique_ptr now with two custom deleters where I call SDL_DestroyWindow and SDL_GL_DeleteContext. I think this will work and it's admittedly not too much bloat either.

Comment: Your remark regarding contexts being tied to the corresponding SDL window is factually wrong. There is *no* connection between an OpenGL context and drawables (windows, GDI/GLX PBuffers, etc.). This is a common misconception (in part informed by some unlucky API design). SDL is one of the few framework, that actually gets this right.

Comment: Ah, upon re-reading SDL documentation, the window and context are indeed independant, I usually use GLFW now, which works as I described in here iirc. Thanks for correcting me - I haven't used SDL in a while haha